# Doctrine Query Builder: How to perform a left join

Tags: mysql, json, symfony, doctrine

I'm searching for a way to perform a left join in Symfony with the query builder on a table where:

Table ***cars***:

| id | image_uuids (json column) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["fb9d77ab-4e8d-4d5e-b439-7cbc5009c230", "be21617a-4ff1-446f-ae09-7f1a53e70b05"] |

Table ***images***:

| id | uuid | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fb9d77ab-4e8d-4d5e-b439-7cbc5009c230 | red |
| 2 | be21617a-4ff1-446f-ae09-7f1a53e70b05 | blue |

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->select(*)
    ->from('cars', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c', 'images', 'carImages', 'carImages.uuid IN ('t.image_uuids');

$resultSet = $queryBuilder->executeQuery();
```

In the response this just returns an empty array for the `carImages` property, I'm looking for all the properties of the `carImages` property.

Comment: Looks like potentially 2 typos `->select('*')`, also what does `t` refer to in your `t.image_uuids` criteria? the query should be erroring with "unknown table or alias name `t`", appears you meant to use `c.image_uuids`.

Comment: You would also need to unpack the JSON using `json_decode()` or similar, since the column value is ultimately a string in the database. I don't believe the DBAL would work with the MySQL [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, or `JSON_CONTAINS` functionality, Normally it would be something like `ON JSON_CONTAINS(c.image_uuids->'$[*]', CAST(carImages.uuid as JSON))`

Comment: You mixed too much things:

 - select * doesn't exist in Doctrine,  
 - IN doesn't exist this way in Doctrine
 - alias table t doesn't exist at all
 - you are not trying to perform a JOIN but a WHERE IN clause
 - how will you manage this in your mappings?

Comment: @b126 `$em->getConnection()->createQueryBuilder()` is the DBAL not the ORM. The `IN` appears to be have been expected to handle the `image_uuids` JSON as an array type but is a string in this context.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to perform a JOIN but a WHERE IN, you can do it this way :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    
$in = $qb->select('c.image_uuids')
    ->from('Cars', 'c')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
    
$images = $qb->select('i')
    ->from('Images', 'i')
    ->where($qb->expr()->in('i.uuid', $in))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

But keep in mind that this is not a clean way to do it.

Even in terms of basic database structure, you should think about creating a standard One-To-Many relationship (one car can have multiple images) or even a Many-To-Many relationship (multiple cars can share same or different images).